# Flutter, many StatefulWidget would be a problem?

Tags: flutter

I want to create and manage many stateful widgets, (for clean code)

but I am afraid that many stateful widgets will create memory issues.

In general, how many stateful widgets can be nested without issue? (assume, the widget size to a minimum (like one Container widget))

how can I check the memory cost of one stateful widget? In android studio?

For example, suppose you have 100 stateful widgets nested. This will be much slower than writing all the code in one stateful widget class, right? Or is there not much difference in speed or memory? So, you can freely use like 100 nested Stateful Widgets?

Answer (score 3):

Many Stateful widgets won’t cause a problem for memory, but I’d highly recommend using a state manager like ‘flutter_bloc’ so you can create more stateless widgets while bloc can still provide state management for your widgets.

Comment: Can I check the memory comparison with when I create a Container in one class and when I create a child StatefulWidget Class again and create a Container there? I want to check physically if I am able to do that.